# Make UIView rotate with it's viewController's orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

**Edit:** I've updated the question and title. It seems like the problem is that the UIView added in my own init isn't actually doing anything other than rotate. Do I really have to handle rotating for a UIView? I tried `[self.overlay addConstraints:[self.view constraints]];` with no luck. I realize that this might be fixed with `[self.overlay setFrame:self.view.frame];` inside `viewDidAppear`, but I'd rather never do **anything** inside that method.

Until now I've always used Storyboard to design my View Controllers. This time, I'm simply writing a few lines of code to show a view, but it seems like the created view in the controller's init won't take my orientation into account. Using Storyboard and instantiating ViewController's by name etc, it works. Now, I'm instantiating it myself, with a custom init-method, which I think is the problem. My custom ViewController simply has this init method and some rotating-delegates:

```
-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
        self.overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [self.view addSubview:self.overlay];
        self.url = url;
    }
    return self;
}

/* viewDidLoad etc.. */

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

To show this modally, I use this in the currently showing controller:

```
CustomViewController *cvc = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithURL: url];
[cvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentViewController:cvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

(Or any other transitionStyle)

The result is shown in the image below:
[image: Wrongly displayed landscape]
The gray area is the new UIView within the CustomViewController which is created in the init. The black area is `self.view`, and aligns properly. If I allow portrait and rotating, it aligns perfectly as it should in portrait, but never in landscape. It seems like `self.overlay` in the presented modal customViewController won't rotate properly. **Am I overriding some rules by replacing any of the `init` methods or something?** When doing this via the Storyboard, it displays correctly in landscape.

Comment: Try returning NO from shouldAutorotate.

Comment: @danh Thanks, but that's not a part of the problem. Even if I remove all methods about rotating (all methods other than `initWithURL`) it still happens.  The only difference is that it shows correctly in portrait, but not in landscape. It actually seems like the UIView inside the UIViewController remains in portrait even when the device and controller is in landscape..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here. It turns out that the added UIView was indeed rotating, but not changing its width and height to be in landscape, thus being taller than the screen, and too slim. Setting the autoresizeMask fixed my issue:

```
overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[overlay setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```